# Django manytomanyfield model error AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'item_set'

Tags: django, loops, model

My Django models look like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
 title = models.TextField()
 price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
 description = models.TextField()
 menu = models.ForeignKey('Menu')

 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToManyField('Item')
    customer = models.ForeignKey('customer.Customer')
    bulkOrder = models.ForeignKey('BulkOrder', default=0)

    @property
    def price(self):
       total = 0
       for item in self.item.all():
           total+=item.price
       return total
```

When I run:

```
I1 = Item(title="Phad Thai", price=7.3, description="Skinny noddles", menu=M1)
I1.save()
O1 = Order(customer=C1, bulkOrder=B1)
O1.item.add(I1)
O1.save()
O1.price

      34         def price(self):
      35          total = 0
  --->36          for item in self.item.all():
      37              total+=item.price
                  return total

      AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'item_set'
```

Yet if I do this in the shell:

```
IN: O1.item.all()
OUT: [<Item: Phad See Ew>, <Item: Phad Thai>]
```

I've looked at similar examples on StackOverflow but they're all a little different from my problem

Comment: Your code doesn't match your error. Where are you running this?

Comment: In the python django shell. I don't get why it says item_set when it is clearly self.item.all()

Comment: Okay nvm I am going to close this because I am stupid and didn't close out of the python shell before editing my error.